# What's a good resource to strengthen your emunah?

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah

If I go for longer than a week without a good shiur I find my emunah begins to wane.
However after going to the same shiur for a while the material can become boring and it looses its effect.

Is there any good resource online or text that one can use to strengthen his or her emunah?

Comment: The Psalms, of course. (I highly recommend R Hirsch's comments on it)

Comment: IMHO, there is a very open-ended question and caters to highly subjective answers. If I could, I would vote for it to be fine-tuned.

Comment: I think the question would be a better fit for the site if it more closely followed the format of this one: http://judaism.stackexchange.com//questions/190/experience-based-advice-for-focusing-and-slowing-down-prayers asking for experience-based advice rather than opinion. (cc: @Lee who brought up basically the same point).

Comment: you answered it yourself - talmud torah. a little light dispels alot of darkness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard from several Rabbanim that one of the best sources for strengthening *emunah* is reading *parshat Ha-Mahn*, which you will find listed after *Shacharit* in most *Siddurim*.

Many people don't say this at all, and those that do, probably run through it too quickly and routinely to appreciate its true messages. *Parshat Ha-mahn* is more than just reading a history lesson and is more than just a lesson about relying on G-d for *parnassa* (one's essential needs). It is mainly about *emunah*.

Think about it. Why didn't G-d just leave the mahn like a huge supermarket where there was so much of it that people could take a lot and store some of it for later? In the story, you see what happened to people that left over the mahn. It got wormy and melted. So every day, people had to go into the field to gather mahn for just that day. Why? To teach people their *emunah*. How did everyone know that the next day they wouldn't have mahn? Indeed, that's what happened to some people on Shabbat when they went and didn't find it. They thought The mahn had ended! Only when Moshe reminded them, that it was just on Shabbat that they wouldn't have mahn (which is why on Friday they took a double portion) were they re-assured. That was a temporary lack of *emunah*.

In short, try reading *parshat ha-mahn* daily. Read it with some good commentaries, perhaps, so that you can understand and better appreciate how G-d provides everything you need each day, **every day**. It is more than just a historical lesson of *emunah*. Its message is highly applicable to all of us today, as well.

*Behatzlacha Ve'emunah*